# Transfer Security into Amazon S3

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the Laravel with PHP League Flysystem for handling file uploads through Amazon AWS S3Client.

However I cannot find any documentation on the security in the transfer from my server into Amazon S3. Is the transfer always encrypted from server to S3?

If you can point to the official documentation that would also be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer in the PHP SDK. It states that the PHP AWS SDK uses HTTPS as default.

From https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/docs/guide/configuration.rst#scheme

```
scheme

:Type: ``string``
:Default: ``string(5) "https"``

URI scheme to use when connecting connect. The SDK will utilize "https"
endpoints (i.e., utilize SSL/TLS connections) by default. You can attempt to
connect to a service over an unencrypted "http" endpoint by setting ``scheme``
to "http".

.. code-block:: php

$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => '2006-03-01',
    'region'  => 'us-west-2',
    'scheme'  => 'http'
]);

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html for a list of
endpoints whether or not a service supports the ``http`` scheme.
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, have a look to this aws documentation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingEncryption.html

Comment: It states "Client-side encryption refers to encrypting data before sending it to Amazon S3". But my question is regarding the transfer security. Is the transfer happening over SSL by default?